# How do I improve the efficiency of the queries executed by this generic Linq-to-SQL data access class?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq-to-sql

I have a class which provides generic access to LINQ to SQL entities, for example:

```
class LinqProvider<T> //where T is a L2S entity class
{
    DataContext context;

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return context.GetTable<T>();
    }

    public virtual T Single(Func<T, bool> condition)
    {
        return context.GetTable<T>().SingleOrDefault(condition);
    }
}
```

From the front end, both of these methods appear to work as you would expect. However, when I run a trace in SQL profiler, the Single method is executing what amounts to a `SELECT * FROM [Table]`, and then returning the single entity that meets the given condition. Obviously this is inefficient, and is being caused by `GetTable()` returning all rows.

My question is, how do I get the query executed by the `Single()` method to take the form `SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE [condition]`, rather than selecting all rows then filtering out all but one? Is it possible in this context?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `Func<...>` with `Expression<Func<...>>`.

Comment: Excellent, just tested this and it works a charm. Very simple and I don't have to change any of the consuming code. Much thanks!